# Pyinstaller isn't recognizable when trying to convert into .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm trying to convert my game that I created with pygame into a .exe file using pyinstaller. For some reason, it does not work. However, it says that I have it installed but it's not reconizable for some reason. Here are some images:

[When I try to run it using: pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0toi4.png)

[This image is when I try to uninstall and reinstall pyinstaller. It currently says that it's installed but when I try to use the command:
"pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py", it says it isn't recognized.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1P92.png)

I'm really desperate... I've searched the ENTIRE internet for a solution but couldn't find one and this is my FIRST stack overflow post. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding pyinstaller to your path, you should be able to find it's folder inside the scripts folder for python, and then also check which pip version you are using if you have multiple versions of python.

Answer (score 0):

If pyinstaller is compatible with 3.9 (which it should be according to the documentation [https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/#:~:text=Works%20out%2Dof%2Dthe%2D,libraries%2C%20thus%20ensuring%20full%20compatibility.&text=Libraries%20like%20PyQt5%2C%20PySide2%2C%20wxPython,or%20external%20data%20files%20manually](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/#:%7E:text=Works%20out%2Dof%2Dthe%2D,libraries%2C%20thus%20ensuring%20full%20compatibility.&text=Libraries%20like%20PyQt5%2C%20PySide2%2C%20wxPython,or%20external%20data%20files%20manually)), then make sure you're running the version of python that has pyinstaller on it. It looks like you're using windows which I don't think has a default python package (mac comes with 2.7 installed which is hella annoying). So if you do have other python versions installed, you need to specify which one you you want to run - in this case 3.9 because that's where. The command I used on mac (I think it should be the same on windows) is

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pyinstaller -m PyInstaller --onefile MyPythonProgram.py
```

That first portion is the location of the pyinstaller folder in your python installation so it will be different from mine but from the `-m` onwards it should be the same. To get the location of pyinstaller try the directory from your second picture.